# Have problem with maintaining session in a Website sone in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Well as I have posted earlier too...I have created a site in two languages.One with URL www.mainDomain.com(English) and other with www.fr.subDomain.com(French).Both are done in CakePHP,in french I have just changed the views of it to French.But the problem is,when anybody login's in English version and then switches to the French version,the session does'nt recognizes it and ask for login again.It has become to be the biggest bug in the Web application which I have done till far.How can manage this thing? Is there any way so that I can manage session on the same time?Please suggest me some thing,so that I can resolve this thing...!!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this may help you: http://www.cake-toppings.com/tag/subdomains/

Comment: Yeah, your session is only stored for one domain by default.  So the .fr subdomain doesn't have any session info.  Read the link that Swanny posted, and the first thing is fixing the subdomain issue for cookies (which is how sessions are stored).

Comment: hey Thanks a lot to both of you...You ppl really rock man...!!!
it was just a piece of cake after this...thanks Swanny thanks a ton...!!!